# Interface Java Applet using Visual Basic

Tags: java, vb.net, applet

Can you point me to a reference on accessing data in a Java applet using Visual Basic? I need to do some research on whether or not it is feasible for the project I am working on, but it has been difficult to find any information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best be will probably be to use something like ComfyJ to create a COM object written in Java so that your VB.NET app can utilize it.

[ComfyJ Features](http://www.teamdev.com/comfyj/features/#java-2-com)

It's a commercial solution, but unless you have your Java application serialize its data to XML or JSON and then read the data back in using .NET...I think it's the only way to go.

I also found [jnBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/jnbpro.htm) which is a Java to .NET bridge that might help as well. It looks like it can use different methods like Shared Memory to Binary Serialization to accomplish your goal.